# Blank pixels left when NSWindow with opaque set to NO

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I have a NSWindow where I set opaque attribute to `NO`. The problem is that when I put any view inside that window it's corners has *blank* pixels.

Everything works well when opaque attribue is left with `YES` value, however, window's corners are not rounded anymore. See picture:

[image]

I've created repository with simple example project at bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/lukaszb/animationartifacts

Is there a way I can fix this (remain window's corners rounded and blank pixels not appearing)? Or should I try another solution (without `setOapque:NO` at `NSWindow` subclass)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling the Core Animation layer for your `RoundedView`, i.e., open `MainMenu.xib`, select `RoundedView` and in the “View Effects” tab (rightmost one) check the view under “Core Animation Layer”.

Alternatively you can do it programmatically, e.g., in `RoundedView` add:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    self.wantsLayer = YES;
    self.layer = [CALayer layer];
    self.layer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor blackColor] CGColor];
    self.layer.cornerRadius = RADIUS;
}
```

Also `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and add `QuartzCore.framework` to the project. You can then delete the `drawRect` method since `CALayer` already does rounded corners for you. (Actually you can delete your whole `RoundedView` class if you just set up this layer for a regular `NSView` that you use in its place.)

Comment: Unfortunately that makes window's corners sharp, not rounded anymore :/

Comment: This would be strange as by setting background color on window, whole bounds should be filled with that color (that's why I use clear color in the first place) - at least that's what I understand should be going.

Comment: @lukaszb See revised answer and try if it works now? I definitely get it working with rounded corners, but I might previously have attributed its working to the wrong edit. =)

Comment: thanks, yep that actually fixes the problem with *blank pixels*. However, the issue is now performance. It wasn't best from the beginning but now when you press enter a few times it looks odd. I've updated repository with your changes.

Anyway, should I file another question related with performance or should I wait for more answers?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Subclass of NSView, make a custom drawing using NSBezierPath in it's drawRect: method, and then set it as the content view of the window.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. See https://bitbucket.org/lukaszb/animationartifacts/src/da98fa1af9c760fdc29b8c289315875fc468aacc/AnimationArtifacts/RoundedView.m?at=master#cl-25